# Any way to compile the firebreath as static library?

Tags: macos, firebreath

Now I am trying to develop a browser plugin with firebreath on mac os.
Although I managed to generate a project and eveything went just fine, but
once I move the project generated with the fbgen.py procedure to somewhere
else, it doesn't work any more. Is there any way for me to take use of
firebreath as a static library like many other third party frameworks? Thus
I can link my project to any other library. Someone managed to do this on
windows platform but I failed to get contact with him.
Any kind of advice would be appreciated.
Regards,
Jordan

Answer (score 1):

All the libraries are statically linked to generate the plugin. The project generated by fbgen.py compiles into static libraries from the source which are then linked to for the plugin. You just have to keep your source files for the plugin with you. You can generate the project anywhere you want using the prep**** scripts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice. Now I am able to generate to the requested folder. But the problem is that I can not link to any other library like openssl/libcurl in my firebreath project

Comment: http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Using+Libraries - This link will help you to link any C++ library to your plugin project. The linking of the library to your plugin depends on how the library was compiled(static or shared). So if you link a shared library with your plugin, then you'll have to keep the shared library along with the plugin otherwise plugin won't work.